# Android: Want to set custom font to entire applicaton using styles.xml or any other options

Tags: android

i am working on implementation of custom font in android application..i want to use one custom font for entire application using styles.XML or may be another options is any.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy built-in way to do this in Android.

You might want to check out [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy), an open source project that makes it easy to change the font for a whole app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn't find a way to do it with .xml files,
at end I inheritance TextView and EditText and apply the font by code

1. put the .otf files at assets/fonts library in your project
2. create a TextViewFont class that inheritance from TextView

   public class TextViewFont extends TextView
   {
       private int mType = 0;

   ```
   public TextViewFont(Context context) 
   {
       this(context,null,0);
   }

   public TextViewFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {

       this(context,attrs,0);
   }


   public TextViewFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
   {
       super(context,attrs,defStyle);
       init(context,attrs);
   }
   public void setType(int type){
       this.mType= type;
       Typeface tf;
       switch (mType)
       {
       case 0:
           tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/xxx-light.otf");
           setTypeface(tf);
           break;
       case 1:
           tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/xxx-regular.otf");
           setTypeface(tf);
           break;
       case 2:
           tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/xxx-bold.otf");
           setTypeface(tf);
           break;
       }
   }
   private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
   {
       if (attrs != null)
       {
           TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                   attrs,
                   R.styleable.TextViewFont,
                   0, 0);

           try 
           {
               TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
               if (a.getValue(0, tv))
               {
                   mType = (int)tv.data;
               }
               mType = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TextViewFont_fontType,0);
           } 
           finally 
           {
               a.recycle();
           }
       }
       if (!isInEditMode())
       {
           Typeface tf;
           switch (mType)
           {
           case 0:
               tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/xxx-light.otf");
               setTypeface(tf);
               break;
           case 1:
               tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/xxx-regular.otf");
               setTypeface(tf);
               break;
           case 2:
               tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/xxx-bold.otf");
               setTypeface(tf);
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

3.Using example inside xml layout file

in the header of the file you use the custom view add

```
     xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and add the custom class as any other view element

```xml
<xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.TextViewFont
        android:id="@+id/xxxxx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="abcdEFGH 123"
        android:textAppearance="@style/xxxxxxx"
        custom:fontType="Regular" />
```

4. define the custom xml attributes vlaues/attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TextViewFont">
        <attr name="fontType" format="enum">
            <enum name="Light" value="0"/>
            <enum name="Regular" value="1"/>
            <enum name="Bold" value="2"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```